# Javascript variables into an SQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am trying to create a page that will keep track of a user's clicks on the site and store the data from their clicks into a database (like the X and Y coordinates on the page, window size, things like that). I've found that it's fairly easy to obtain this information using Javascript's mouse event properties, the problem is that now that I have the information, I can't seem to figure out how to send the data to an SQL database I've created to store the information. I would preferably like to do this in the form of a query but the only way I can think of doing that is with PHP, problem is that it's a lot easier to get PHP into Javascript than it is to get Javascript into PHP. Can someone tell me if I'm going about this all wrong? Maybe there's a way I could accomplish this using AJAX or something, I also don't want to have to reload the whole page every time a user clicks to get my data.

For example I have variables in script such as:

```
<script>
var x = event.clientX;
var y = event.clientY;
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight
</script>
```

then I would want to send a query to my server such as:

```
"INSERT INTO click.table (x_coord, y_coord, window_w, window_h) VALUES $x, $y, $width, $height;"
```

Something to that extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try like this

```
<script>
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight

    $.ajax({
        url:"path to php file",
        data:{x:x,y:y,width:width,height:height},
        type:"POST",
        success: function(){
               alert("success");
          }
    });
</script>
```

In your php side,

```
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$width = $_POST['width'];
$height = $_POST['height'];
"INSERT INTO click.table (x_coord, y_coord, window_w, window_h) VALUES $x, $y, $width, $height;"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad it helped you:)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the data to a JSON object and save that string in MySQL. AFAIK, as of [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) you can even make MySQL queries on JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to require a lot of server overhead and you will have to "re-create" each screen that each user uses. Ex. If a user on a macbook running chrome clicks on pixel (100,100) whatever html elements that appear there on his computer will be completely different than what an XP user running IE8 would see.

I have tried doing exactly what you're trying to do now. In the end I just decided to outsource it. Try http://www.crazyegg.com/ Doing all the browser simulation and grabbing click data is inefficient and futile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight

    <?php $x ="<script>document.write(x)</script>"?>
    <?php $y ="<script>document.write(y)</script>"?>
    <?php $width ="<script>document.write(width)</script>"?>
    <?php $height ="<script>document.write(height)</script>"?>
</script>
```

**In php**

```
<?php echo $x?>
<?php echo "<br>"?>
<?php echo $y?>
<?php echo "<br>"?>
<?php echo $width?>
<?php echo "<br>"?>
<?php echo $height?>
<?php echo "<br>"?>
```